# Node teaser with a different size than other nodes

Tags: theming, nodes

I have created a content type, and for some reason the teaser text has a different size than the size used by all the other nodes.

This is what happens for "Stenhousemuir For Sunday Success."

[image: screenshot]

Could anyone enlighten me on why this happens?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what you are seeing; a link is not sufficient. Questions must be relevant for future readers, not just for who ask the question.

Comment: I've seen that Louis Theroux episode...it's very creepy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That particular bit of text is wrapped in a `<span>` that includes inline styles that change the font size of that text.

If your content is entered via a WYSIWYG editor, you may want to adjust the settings for that WYSIWYG so that it strips out inline styles like this.

Comment: ah hah so it is Sheena. I see it now. Dunno how that got in there. I will do as you say about the stripping and thank you very much :)